# Octave/Matlab: vectorising '==' operator?

Tags: matlab, operators, find, octave, vectorization

I can look for the position of a value, i.e. 45, in a vector 'data' using the '==' operator and the 'find()' function:

```
data = [ 71 65 23 45 34 12 21 34 52 ];
value = 45;

find (data == value)
ans =  4
```

Is there a way to do the same for several values without using a loop, i.e. i would like to get [ 4 5 7 ] in a single call:

```
values = [ 45 34 21 ];
find (data == values)
error: mx_el_eq: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x9, op2 is 1x3)
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) function:

```
data = [ 71 65 23 45 34 12 21 34 52 ];
values = [ 45 34 21 ];

find(ismember(data, values))
```

Giving:

```
ans =

 4     5     7     8
```

Comment: In fact, this is a lot faster than a method I was about to propose: `find( any( bsxfun( @eq, data, values' ), 1 ) )`. using `tic` `toc` I get that `ismember` is x5 times **faster** than my `bsxfun @eq` method. Well done Bill!